# mysql view is showing 1242 error

Tags: php, mysql, view, mysql-error-1064

I am new to `Views`. I have created a following view

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `My_db`$$

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_affiliate_banner_info_earning_details`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`user`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_affiliate_banner_info_earning_details` AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  `m`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,
  (SELECT
     (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END)
   FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb`
   WHERE (`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`)) AS `my_kash_back`,
  (SELECT
     (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN `v_gk`.`status` ELSE CONVERT((CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) USING latin1) END)
   FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk`
   WHERE (`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`)) AS `my_community_kash`,
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END) FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb` WHERE ((`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_cb`.`status` = 'pending'))) + (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN '0.00' ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) END) FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk` WHERE ((`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_gk`.`status` = 'pending')))),2)) AS `pending`,
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END) FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb` WHERE ((`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_cb`.`status` = 'available'))) + (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN '0.00' ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) END) FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk` WHERE ((`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_gk`.`status` = 'available')))),2)) AS `available`
FROM ((`view_members` `m`
    LEFT JOIN `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb`
      ON ((`m`.`member_id` = `v_cb`.`member_id`)))
   LEFT JOIN `view_good_bonus` `v_gk`
     ON ((`m`.`member_id` = `v_gk`.`cash_back_to`)))
WHERE 1
ORDER BY `m`.`member_id`)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

At the time of creation it doesn't give me any error, but when I want to see the data in this view, it gives me following error
**Subquery returns more than 1 row**

### Update

I changed the query like this, but still the same

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `my_db`$$

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_affiliate_banner_info_earning_details`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`user`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_affiliate_banner_info_earning_details` AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  `m`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,
  (SELECT
     (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END)
   FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb`
   WHERE (`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) LIMIT 1) AS `my_kash_back`,
  (SELECT
     (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN `v_gk`.`status` ELSE CONVERT((CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) USING latin1) END)
   FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk`
   WHERE (`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) LIMIT 1) AS `my_community_kash`,
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END) FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb` WHERE ((`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_cb`.`status` = 'pending'))) + (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN '0.00' ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) END) FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk` WHERE ((`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_gk`.`status` = 'pending')))),2)) AS `pending`,
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END) FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb` WHERE ((`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_cb`.`status` = 'available'))) + (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN '0.00' ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) END) FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk` WHERE ((`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_gk`.`status` = 'available')))),2)) AS `available`
FROM ((`view_members` `m`
    LEFT JOIN `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb`
      ON ((`m`.`member_id` = `v_cb`.`member_id`)))
   LEFT JOIN `view_good_bonus` `v_gk`
     ON ((`m`.`member_id` = `v_gk`.`cash_back_to`)))
WHERE 1
ORDER BY `m`.`member_id`)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Either v_cb or v_gk is returning multiple rows per member_id. Based on the names alone, I'd look at v_gk first, and applying some other constraint to make it pull only 1 row.

Comment: I fixed it by creating this view again, this was messed up because of duplication of data in my table

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

What is the issue?  You have two subqueries in the `select` clause.  One of them is returning more than one row.  The fix-it-fast approach is to just add `limit 1` to both the subqueries.

In fact, we can narrow this down.  The first subquery is an aggregation subquery, so it returns only one row.  The problem is the second one:

```
  (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN `v_gk`.`status` ELSE CONVERT((CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) USING latin1) END)
   FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk`
   WHERE (`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`)
  ) AS `my_community_kash`,
```

You can do a fast-and-dirty fix by putting a `limit 1` after the `where`.  You can fix it by putting an aggregation function in the `select` clause (as with the first query).  Or, you can figure out why the data doesn't behave the way you think it does and fix either the data or the query or both, as appropriate.

EDIT:

When I first answered, I missed that there are more than two correlated subqueries rather  The others are in these expressions (which inconveniently scroll off the page):

```
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END) FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb` WHERE ((`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_cb`.`status` = 'pending'))) + (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN '0.00' ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) END) FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk` WHERE ((`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_gk`.`status` = 'pending')))),2)) AS `pending`,
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_cb`.`kash_back`),2),2) END) FROM `view_member_cash_back` `v_cb` WHERE ((`v_cb`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_cb`.`status` = 'available'))) + (SELECT (CASE WHEN (`v_gk`.`status` = 'upgrade') THEN '0.00' ELSE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),0)) THEN '0.00' ELSE TRUNCATE(ROUND(SUM(`v_gk`.`good_bonus`),2),2) END) END) FROM `view_good_bonus` `v_gk` WHERE ((`v_gk`.`cash_back_to` = `m`.`member_id`) AND (`v_gk`.`status` = 'available')))),2)) AS `available`
```

One of these may also be returning more than row, so including the `limit 1` clause in all of them should fix the problem.

Comment: it executes finely but when i go to see the data, it gives the same error. See my update, I changed the query

Comment: @baig772 . . . I missed the last two correlated subqueries.  That must be where the problem is.